# Many ArrayList into Classes

Tags: design-patterns

I'm a kind of new to programming and i wish a simple advice how to proceed. I'll simply explain my situation.

I have a webpage (Default.aspx), 2 classes (Class1, Class2) and 15 ArrayLists.

Step 1) In Default.aspx when a user click a button i create a new instance of Class1:

```
Class1 objClass1 = new Class1();
```

Step 2) In Class1, i have 15 ArrayLists where i add data to them. I don't know the number of elements and i use ArrayList object, not simple arrays. I fill all 15 ArrayLists with data in Class1. All the ArrayLists contain between 10-150 items in them.

Step 3) In Class2 i need all 15 ArrayLists to do some business rules on them in routine Class2BusinessRules. So, i code:

```
Class2 objClass2 = new Class1(); 
objClass2.Class2BusinessRules(ArrayList1, ArrayList2, etc..)
```

So, i pass 15 arraylists as parameters to Class2. What is a better solution to this situation? Class1 and Class2 should exist separately, because they are abstract objects, they serve different purposes. I don't want to merge them into 1 class. I don't want to make these 15 ArrayLists static or any kind of global variables, because concurrent users on the website will use them.

Possible solutions:
1) Put all ArrayLists in a separate class
2) Put all ArrayLists into a Dictionay object like Dictionary

What are pros/cons for these 2 solution? Can you share other approriate solutions for my case? Can you tell me any design patter for classes close to my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass a reference to Class1 into Class2. That way inside Class2 you cen access the array lists by the Class1 reference.
e.g.

```
  Class2 objClass2 = new Class1(objClass1);
```

Comment: @user569008 This seems to me to be the simplest approach since you only have a single object to pass, I guess the second approach of storing them in another structure can be made to work too. My perfsonal preference is this solution.

Comment: In Class1 i have other public members like properties and methods which i don't want to send / allow to Class2. Also i think it's not efficiant to send so much data from Class1 which won't be used in Class2.

Comment: In that case storing all the array lists in another collection would do just as well.

Comment: But what to choose, what are the pros/cons of both? Is there a design pattern cocnerning which is close to this case?